# Microsoft Graph API: can't list recurring events of a meeting room

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-calendar

I'm building a Ruby on Rails app where the events within an organization are grouped & shown by the meeting rooms using the Microsoft Graph API with the app only authorization flow described in the below link.

http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/authorization/app_only

I am using the following request to list the events of a meeting room

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<meeting room email>/events
```

But the thing is that not all the events are being listed for the upcoming weeks and I suppose those are the recurring events.

Is there any way to include the recurring events into the results.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution, calendarView method is listing all events for a given time range in ISO 8601 format

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<meeting room email>/calendarView/?endDateTime=2015-12-28T22:23:00Z&startDateTime=2015-12-28T00:00:00Z
```

[List calendarView Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: "The specified object was not found in the store." ? is there any permissons process to do ?( https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/calendar_list_calendarview)

Comment: @julestruong If I remember right "Read user calendars" and "Have full access to user calendars" in delegated permissions should be enough. But changes in app permissions on Azure don't affect immediately. It may take some time to be applied.

Comment: Also, you can use the Microsoft Graph API explorer to test your endpoints. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer