# Android and Exchange WS SOAP API

Tags: java, android, exchangewebservices, ksoap2, httpsurlconnection

I need to call [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204119%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) sending SOAP messages over HTTPS.

1) Nowadays what fits better?

- [HTTPSUrlConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html)
- [Ksoap2](https://github.com/simpligility/ksoap2-android)

2) How do I get started to login into EWS, use [SOAP Autodiscovery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877090%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) to discover the url endpoint and finally send the SOAP XML requests (EWS operations)?

Thanks

Comment: Look at this repo: https://github.com/alipov/ews-android-api

Comment: Does that API allow delegate access? It's not mentioned in the documentation so doesn't fit my purpose and I have to stick with the SOAP api. Outlook REST API will (probably) allow delegate access just from July 2016 - see my original question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976578/outlook-read-another-users-calendar

Comment: PS. I used loopj AsyncHttpClient and raw xml messages